# looping through a list and output in Json

Tags: python, json

How can I have my Json output like this :

```
["fields": [{"name" : "id"},{"name":"item"},{"name":"some"}]]
```

Knowing that the `names` are stored in a list like this :

```
l = [ "id","item","some"]
```

I have tried this :

```
 print json.dumps({'success': True, 'fields' : {'name' : s} for s in l})
```

but it's not working, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't have your Json output precisely like that. It isn't valid JSON. You seem to be confusing a list with a dictionary.

Comment: the json output I actually have is bigger than this. This was just a simplified example.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the square brackets you need for a list comprehension that will make 'fields' a list.

```
import json

l = [ "id","item","some"]
print json.dumps({'success': True, 'fields' : [{'name' : s} for s in l]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [{'name' : s} for s in l]
[{'name': 'id'}, {'name': 'item'}, {'name': 'some'}]

>>> json.dumps({'success': True, 'fields' : [{'name' : s} for s in l]})
'{"success": true, "fields": [{"name": "id"}, {"name": "item"}, {"name": "some"}]}'
```